# Following nested foreign keys while prefetching in Django

Tags: django, nested, prefetch

I have an information model with deep and complex foreign key relations. and lots of them. Because of it I am trying to use `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` to minimize the number of queries to my DB.

I am having the problem, however, that I cannot figure out a way to make pre-fetching operators follow foreign keys to an arbitrary depth. I am aware of the double underscore operator (`__`), but that isn't really an option, because I do not know in advance how deep the nesting will be.

So for example let's say I have objects `A, B, C,...Z`. Any object can have an arbitrary number of foreign keys pointing to any object that appear, say, later on in the alphabet. How can I make sure that, for example, prefetching the foreign key that from `A` points to `B` will follow all the foreign keys on B?

My best shot for now was a semi-hard coded approach on the `get_queryset()` method on the object manager.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**:

Ok so an idea on how I am trying to do it at the moment is as follows:

```
    class MyModelmanager(model.Manger):
        def get_queryset()
            qs = super().get_queryset()
            qs = qs.select_related(*thefiledsiwannaprefetch)
            return qs
```

Now in the fields I am prefetching there are foreign keys relations I would like to follow. How do I achieve that (without using `'__'`)?

**EDIT 2**

Another attempt was the following:

```
    class MyModelmanager(model.Manger):
        def get_queryset()
            return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related()
```

I did then overrode the manger of the other models, so that they also performed prefetching in their `get_queryset()` method. This also didn't work.

Comment: Post the code of how you are trying to do it.

Comment: If you're serializing, DRF has [`depth`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization). If you're sending data to a template, at some point in the code you will actually do something with the data, and this is usually where you would construct the queries to pull the data you need, not less and not more. The approach described essentially pulls all data from the db. I wonder what the use case for that might be. At any rate, you would need [reflection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/meta/) to do that with `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#s-select-related):

> There may be some situations where you wish to call select_related() with a lot of related objects, or where you don’t know all of the relations. In these cases it is possible to call select_related() with no arguments. This will follow all non-null foreign keys it can find - nullable foreign keys must be specified. This is not recommended in most cases as it is likely to make the underlying query more complex, and return more data, than is actually needed.

Comment: Yup, saw that. I also tried and failed miserably. Any suggestion on how that would be implemented in practice?

Comment: You called without any arguments and it didn't work?

Comment: To be clear, this does *not* apply to `prefetch_related`. An empty `prefetch_related` call does nothing.